# How to upload image through retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2, image-uploading

I have looked through many stackoverflow answers but could not upload image. It used to give me `Internal Server Error`. Now I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42578987/8051673) but it sends a null image to the server. Could you please show me where I am doing wrong.

Here is my **Request CODE**:

```
@Multipart
@POST("lostandfound")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadLostAndFound(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map);
```

And my **CALL**:

```
    Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("usermail", toRequestBody("mohammad_sed"));
    map.put("content", toRequestBody(content));
    map.put("islost", toRequestBody(String.valueOf(isLost)));
    map.put("wasfound", toRequestBody(foundPlace));
    map.put("tofind", toRequestBody(toFindPlace));

    File file = new File(destination);


    RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);
    map.put("img", body);

    ForumService client = Utils.getBuilder().create(ForumService.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = client.uploadLostAndFound(map);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Request created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to upload!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // This method  converts String to RequestBody
    public static RequestBody toRequestBody(String value) {
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), value);
        return body;
    }
```

I tried:

```
@Multipart
@POST("lostandfound")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadLostAndFound(@Part MultipartBody.Part photo,
                                      @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map);
```

But this way I get `Internal server error`. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Internal server error" -> "server error" -> "server". The problem is in the server code

Comment: try on postman y log with an interceptor the mobile request and check the diferencies between both request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **found the solution**. 
I tried from `postman` and it was working fine.

The solution is that I had to use:

```
@Multipart
@POST("lostandfound")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadLostAndFound(@Part MultipartBody.Part photo,
                                  @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map);
```

and:

```
RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("img", file.getName(), reqFile);
```

The change is I had to use "img" instead of "upload". That is a stupid mistake :D

Comment: I'm having the same issue , can you give me the all solution .. post the full code please ?

Comment: is img is your backend paramiter?

Comment: @RavishSharma sorry for late reply. Yes it is. https://link.medium.com/uQRhniwVHW check this link out.